# Shortcode, vs blocks, vs templates - what would you do for choosing or creating custom post data in editor?

Tags: shortcode, block-editor

Say you have some custom post type. Call it `my_type`.

Now say in Gutenberg, you want to either

a. Insert some data into a `my_type` post from an existing instance of `another_type` where the inserted block has template/styling

or

b. Insert some data into `my_type` that will create the custom `another_type` post instance.

What is the most sensible methodology?  You can imagine doing this with a forum post. In Gutenberg you want to insert some reusable block with styling that displays certain forum topic data. Or you want to insert a block that creates the forum topic in the first place.

As it is now, I am just creating the forum topic then using a shortcode with topic id, but can't help but wonder if there is a better way?

thanks!
Brian

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your examples, could you give a more specific real-world example?

Comment: So say you have a post type called `lesson`. In lesson editor you want to add a block for a lesson discussion. Discussions are via bbpress where forums are related to a given lesson. So in lesson editor I want to add block for an existing forum topic or add block that creates the forum topic if it doesn't exist. Make sense? thanks, Brian